# Topic subscription Using APNs

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am have an app with push notification implemented in APNs, ie, Firebase has not been used. I need to implement a topic subscription like feature(one present in firebase). Is there a way to implement a topic subscription(One in FCM) or similar option with APNs service? Any heads up is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to manage topic related things on your backend, i-e mobile devices will subscribe to certain topics which are already made at backend, your backend needs to handle all the related things like creating a new topic, assigning respective device token to those topics etc.

I am also looking to work on this